# How do I make hyperlink move to next page taking angularjs variable with it?

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, redirect

I have a table row being populated with the array of Json objects.

I actually want to click one of the row item and move to the next page by also taking the clicked item's id.

My Code:

1. AngularJS function

   ```
           $scope.findAllCompanies = function() {

           $http.get('http://blahblablah/company/all').

           then(function(response) {
               $scope.companyList = response.data;
           });

       }
   ```
2. HTML: traversing the companyList

   ```
       <tr data-ng-repeat="company in companyList"> 

       <td> <a href="/pages/company"> {{company.companyId}} </a>  </td>
       <td> {{company.legalName}} </td>
       <td> {{company.dbaName}} </td>
       <td> {{company.formation}} </td>

   </tr>
   ```

> So now, If I click on companyId in any row, the page should be redirected to company.html?companyId=anyNum

I am thinking to merge them here, something like this:
[image]

Thanks, and looking forward to hear from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

```
<a ng-href="/pages/company?companyId={{company.companyId}}"> {{company.companyId}} </a>
```

Comment: thanks. please tell me how do call the above parameter value in this function data-ng-init="findCompanyById('companyId')

Comment: data-ng-init="findCompanyById('companyId')"     , it is in company.html please help me correct it

Comment: using [$location.search()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#search) you can get the params value

Comment: in `company.html's` controller you can access company id by `$location.search().companyId`